# Arduino Uno with Sensor, Bluetooth Module and tftlcd

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, memory-usage

In code attached below I am using tftlcd display of 2.4 inch in which i want to show clock as home page, when user click on tftlcd screen then a screen appears which can show three options to user which are about the sensors user want to use. There are three sensors in this code: Pulse oximeter, glucose meter, pedometer. After choosing some option(sensor) the data of sensor will appear on screen.
I have write code for all this procedure which is given below:

```
//include all libraries
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPFD5408_Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <SPFD5408_Adafruit_TFTLCD.h>
#include <SPFD5408_TouchScreen.h>
#include "MAX30105.h"
#include "spo2_algorithm.h"

//Exit buttons
bool backsensed = false;
bool resetsensed = false;

//Include Max30102 lib
MAX30105 particleSensor;

//Define LCD pins
#define YP A1  // must be an analog pin, use "An" notation!
#define XM A2  // must be an analog pin, use "An" notation!
#define YM 7   // can be a digital pin
#define XP 6   // can be a digital pin

//pedometer
const int xpin = A3;
const int ypin = A4;
const int zpin = A5;
byte p[8] = {0x1F,
  0x1F,
  0x1F,
  0x1F,
  0x1F,
  0x1F,
  0x1F,
  0x1F
};
float threshold = 100;
float xval[100] = {0};
float yval[100] = {0};
float zval[100] = {0};
float xavg, yavg, zavg;
int steps, flag = 0;
//pulseoxi
#define MAX_BRIGHTNESS 255
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega328P__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega168__)
uint16_t irBuffer[100]; //infrared LED sensor data
uint16_t redBuffer[100];  //red LED sensor data
#else
uint32_t irBuffer[100]; //infrared LED sensor data
uint32_t redBuffer[100];  //red LED sensor data
#endif
int32_t bufferLength; //data length
int32_t spo2; //SPO2 value
int8_t validSPO2; //indicator to show if the SPO2 calculation is valid
int32_t heartRate; //heart rate value
int8_t validHeartRate; //indicator to show if the heart rate calculation is valid
byte pulseLED = 11; //Must be on PWM pin
byte readLED = 13; //Blinks with each data read

// LCD Calibrate values
#define TS_MINX 100
#define TS_MINY 120
#define TS_MAXX 920
#define TS_MAXY 940

// For better pressure precision, we need to know the resistance between X+ and X- Use any multimeter to read it
// For the one we're using, its 300 ohms across the X plate
TouchScreen ts = TouchScreen(XP, YP, XM, YM, 300);

#define LCD_CS A3
#define LCD_CD A2
#define LCD_WR A1
#define LCD_RD A0
#define LCD_RESET A4

Adafruit_TFTLCD tft(LCD_CS, LCD_CD, LCD_WR, LCD_RD, LCD_RESET);

int BLUE = tft.color565(50, 50, 255);
#define TFT_BLACK   0x0000
#define TFT_DARKBLUE 0x0010
#define VIOLET 0x8888
#define TFT_RED     0xF800
#define TFT_GREEN   0x07E0
#define TFT_CYAN    0x07FF
#define TFT_MAGENTA 0xF81F
#define TFT_YELLOW  0xFFE0
#define TFT_WHITE   0xFFFF
#define TFT_GREY    0x5AEB
#define TFT_BLUE    0x001F
#define GOLD 0xFEA0
#define BROWN 0xA145
#define SILVER 0xC618
#define LIME 0x07E0
#define BLUE  0x001F

//button screen
int currentpcolour;
int currentpage;
bool running;

//Minimum and maximum pressure to sense the touch
#define MINPRESSURE 10
#define MAXPRESSURE 1000

//clock
float sx = 0, sy = 1, mx = 1, my = 0, hx = -1, hy = 0;    
float sdeg = 0, mdeg = 0, hdeg = 0;
uint16_t osx = 120, osy = 120, omx = 120, omy = 120, ohx = 120, ohy = 120; 
int16_t x0 = 0, x1 = 0, yy0 = 0, yy1 = 0, x00 = 0, yy00 = 0;
uint32_t targetTime = 0;                    
uint16_t xpos; 
uint8_t conv2d(const char* p) {
  uint8_t v = 0;
  if ('0' <= *p && *p <= '9')
    v = *p - '0';
  return 10 * v + *++p - '0';
}
uint8_t hh = conv2d(__TIME__), mm = conv2d(__TIME__ + 3), ss = conv2d(__TIME__ + 6); 
boolean initial = 1;
char d;

//for buttons
void drawHome()
{
  tft.fillScreen(TFT_BLACK);
  tft.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 319, 240, 8, TFT_YELLOW);     //Page border

  tft.fillRoundRect(60, 180, 200, 40, 8, TFT_DARKBLUE);
  tft.drawRoundRect(60, 180, 200, 40, 8, TFT_YELLOW);  //PEDO

  tft.fillRoundRect(60, 130, 200, 40, 8, TFT_DARKBLUE);   //Glu
  tft.drawRoundRect(60, 130, 200, 40, 8, TFT_YELLOW);

  tft.fillRoundRect(60, 80, 200, 40, 8, TFT_DARKBLUE);
  tft.drawRoundRect(60, 80, 200, 40, 8, TFT_YELLOW); //Pulse oxi and heart rate

  tft.setCursor(25, 20);
  tft.setTextSize(3);
  tft.setTextColor(TFT_WHITE);
  tft.print("Welcome Here..");
  tft.setCursor(25, 50);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.setTextColor(TFT_YELLOW);
  tft.print("Choose Your Sensor");
  tft.setTextColor(TFT_WHITE);
  tft.setCursor(110, 195);
  tft.print("Pedometer");

  tft.setCursor(80, 145);
  tft.print("Glucose Sensor");

  tft.setCursor(80, 95);
  tft.print("Pulse Oximeter");
  //  delay(500);

  }

  void setup()
{
  tft.reset();  
  tft.begin(0x9341); 
  tft.setRotation(1);
  currentpage = 0; //clock page
  tft.setTextColor(TFT_WHITE);// text color
  tft.fillScreen(TFT_BLACK);// background color

  xpos = tft.width() / 2; 
  tft.drawCircle(xpos, 120, 125, TFT_YELLOW);
  tft.fillCircle(xpos, 120, 118, TFT_BLUE); 
  tft.fillCircle(xpos, 120, 110, TFT_BLACK); 
  for (int a=95; a<104; a++){
  tft.drawCircle(xpos, 120, a, TFT_WHITE);}  

 
  for (int i = 0; i < 360; i += 30) {
    sx = cos((i - 90) * 0.0174532925);
    sy = sin((i - 90) * 0.0174532925);
    x0 = sx * 114 + xpos;
    yy0 = sy * 114 + 120;
    x1 = sx * 100 + xpos;
    yy1 = sy * 100 + 120;
    tft.drawLine(x0, yy0, x1, yy1, TFT_YELLOW);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 360; i += 6) {
    sx = cos((i - 90) * 0.0174532925);
    sy = sin((i - 90) * 0.0174532925);
    x0 = sx * 102 + xpos;
    yy0 = sy * 102 + 120;
    x00 = sx * 92 + xpos;
    yy00 = sy * 92 + 120;
    // Draw minute markers
    tft.drawPixel(x0, yy0, TFT_GREEN); 
    tft.drawLine(x0, yy0, x00, yy00, TFT_BLACK);
    tft.drawLine(x0+1, yy0+1, x00+1, yy00+1, TFT_BLACK);
    // Draw main quadrant dots
    if (i == 0 || i == 180) tft.fillCircle(x0, yy0, 2, TFT_WHITE); 
    if (i == 90 || i == 270) tft.fillCircle(x0, yy0, 2, TFT_WHITE); 
  }
  tft.fillCircle(xpos, 121, 3, TFT_WHITE);
  targetTime = millis() + 1000;
  //touch event
  tft.setCursor (80, 250);
  tft.setTextSize (1);
  tft.setTextColor(TFT_BLACK);
  tft.println("Touch to proceed");
  waitOneTouch(); // Wait touch
  drawHome(); //buttons screeen
}

void loop(){
  if (currentpage == 0){
  if (targetTime < millis()) {             //clock code
    targetTime = millis() + 1000;
    ss++;              
    if (ss == 60) {
      ss = 0;
      mm++;            
      if (mm > 59) {
        mm = 0;
        hh++;          
        if (hh > 23) {
          hh = 0;
        }
      }
    }
    sdeg = ss * 6;                     // 0-59 -> 0-354
    mdeg = mm * 6 + sdeg * 0.01666667; // 0-59 -> 0-360 - includes seconds, but these increments are not used
    hdeg = hh * 30 + mdeg * 0.0833333; // 0-11 -> 0-360 - includes minutes and seconds, but these increments are not used
    hx = cos((hdeg - 90) * 0.0174532925);
    hy = sin((hdeg - 90) * 0.0174532925);
    mx = cos((mdeg - 90) * 0.0174532925);
    my = sin((mdeg - 90) * 0.0174532925);
    sx = cos((sdeg - 90) * 0.0174532925);
    sy = sin((sdeg - 90) * 0.0174532925);
    if (ss == 0 || initial) {
      initial = 0;
      // Erase hour and minute hand positions every minute
      tft.drawLine(ohx, ohy, xpos, 121, TFT_BLACK);
      ohx = hx * 62 + xpos + 1;
      ohy = hy * 62 + 121;
      tft.drawLine(omx, omy, xpos, 121, TFT_BLACK);
      omx = mx * 84 + xpos;
      omy = my * 84 + 121;
    }
    // Redraw new hand positions, hour and minute hands not erased here to avoid flicker
    tft.drawLine(osx, osy, xpos, 121, TFT_BLACK);
    osx = sx * 90 + xpos + 1;
    osy = sy * 90 + 121;
    tft.drawLine(osx, osy, xpos, 121, TFT_RED);
    tft.drawLine(ohx, ohy, xpos, 121, TFT_CYAN);
    tft.drawLine(omx, omy, xpos, 121, TFT_WHITE);
    tft.drawLine(osx, osy, xpos, 121, TFT_RED);
    tft.fillCircle(xpos, 121, 3, TFT_RED);
    tft.setCursor(xpos-30, 50);
    tft.setTextSize(2);
    tft.print("Glucoxy");
 
  // Draw MINI clock face "SECOND"
  tft.drawCircle(xpos, 155, 20, TFT_YELLOW);
  tft.drawCircle(xpos, 155, 18, TFT_BLUE);
  tft.drawCircle(xpos, 155, 17, TFT_CYAN);
  tft.drawCircle(xpos, 155, 16, TFT_CYAN);
  tft.fillRect(xpos-10, 149,22,15,TFT_BLACK); //erase
  if(ss<10){tft.setCursor(xpos-10, 149); tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.print('0'); tft.setCursor(xpos+2, 149);}
  else{
  tft.setCursor(xpos-10, 149);}
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.print(ss);
  // Draw MINI clock face "Minutes"
  tft.drawCircle(xpos+35, 117, 20, TFT_YELLOW);
  tft.drawCircle(xpos+35, 117, 18, TFT_BLUE);
  tft.drawCircle(xpos+35, 117, 17, TFT_CYAN);
  tft.drawCircle(xpos+35, 117, 16, TFT_CYAN);
 tft.fillRect(xpos+25, 111,22,15,TFT_BLACK); //erase
  if(mm<10){tft.setCursor(xpos+25, 111); tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.print('0'); tft.setCursor(xpos+37, 111);}
  else{
  tft.setCursor(xpos+25, 111);}
  tft.println(mm);
  // Draw MINI clock face "Hour"
  tft.drawCircle(xpos-35, 117, 20, TFT_YELLOW);
  tft.drawCircle(xpos-35, 117, 18, TFT_BLUE);
  tft.drawCircle(xpos-35, 117, 17, TFT_CYAN);
  tft.drawCircle(xpos-35, 117, 16, TFT_CYAN);
  tft.fillRect(xpos-45, 111,22,15,TFT_BLACK); //erase
  if(hh<10){tft.setCursor(xpos-45, 111); tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.print('0'); tft.setCursor(xpos-33, 111);}
  else{
  tft.setCursor(xpos-45, 111);}
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.print(hh);
  //tft.setCursor(xpos-65, 111);
  //tft.println(':');
  if (hh>=0 && hh<12) d='A'; else {d='P';}
  tft.drawRoundRect(xpos-14,72,29,21,5,TFT_CYAN);
  tft.fillRect(xpos-11, 75,23,15,TFT_BLACK); //erase
  tft.setCursor(xpos-11, 75);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.print(d);
  tft.println('M');
  }
  }
  //home page
  if (currentpage == 1){
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  TSPoint p = ts.getPoint();     // Read touchscreen
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  pinMode(XM, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(YP, OUTPUT);
  {if (p.z > 10 && p.z < 1000)
    {
      if (p.x > 736 && p.x < 855 && p.y > 255 && p.y < 725  && p.z > MINPRESSURE && p.z < MAXPRESSURE)
      {
        Serial.println("Pedometer");
        tft.fillRoundRect(60, 180, 200, 40, 8, TFT_WHITE);
        delay(70);
        tft.fillRoundRect(60, 180, 200, 40, 8, TFT_WHITE);
        tft.drawRoundRect(60, 180, 200, 40, 8, TFT_YELLOW);
        tft.setCursor(65, 195);
        tft.println("  Pedometer");
        delay(70);
        currentpage = 2;
        startPedo();
      }
      else if (p.x > 563 && p.x < 683 && p.y > 275 && p.y < 750)
      {
        Serial.println("Glucose Sensor");

        tft.fillRoundRect(60, 130, 200, 40, 8, TFT_WHITE);   //rgb led
        delay(70);
        tft.fillRoundRect(60, 130, 200, 40, 8, TFT_WHITE);   //rgb led
        tft.drawRoundRect(60, 130, 200, 40, 8, TFT_YELLOW);   //rgb led
        tft.setCursor(105, 145);
        tft.print("Glucose Sensor");
        delay(70);
        currentpage = 3;
        startGlu();
      }
      if (p.x > 403 && p.x < 525 && p.y > 271 && p.y < 725)
      {
        Serial.println("Pulse Oximeter");
        currentpage = 4;
        tft.fillRoundRect(60, 80, 200, 40, 8, TFT_WHITE);
        delay(70);
        tft.fillRoundRect(60, 80, 200, 40, 8, TFT_WHITE);
        tft.drawRoundRect(60, 80, 200, 40, 8, TFT_YELLOW);
        tft.setCursor(80, 95);
        tft.print("Pulse Oximeter");
        delay(70);
       // startPulse();

      }
    }
  }
  if (currentpage == 2) //pedo
  {
    senseBack();
    if (backsensed)
    {
      currentpage = 1;
      drawHome();
    }
    sensereset();
    calibrate();
  }
  if (currentpage == 3) // glucose
  {
     senseBack();
     if (backsensed)
     {
      currentpage = 0;
      drawHome();
     }
    sensereset();
  }

  if (currentpage == 4)  //pulse oxi
  {
    senseBack();
     if (backsensed)
     {
      currentpage = 1;
      drawHome();
     }
    sensereset();
    pinMode(pulseLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(readLED, OUTPUT);
  if (!particleSensor.begin(Wire, I2C_SPEED_FAST)) //Use default I2C port, 400kHz speed  // Initialize sensor
  {
    Serial.println(F("MAX30105 was not found. Please check wiring/power."));
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println(F("Attach sensor to finger with rubber band. Press any key to start conversion"));
  while (Serial.available() == 0) ; //wait until user presses a key
  Serial.read();
  byte ledBrightness = 60; //Options: 0=Off to 255=50mA
  byte sampleAverage = 4; //Options: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32
  byte ledMode = 2; //Options: 1 = Red only, 2 = Red + IR, 3 = Red + IR + Green
  byte sampleRate = 100; //Options: 50, 100, 200, 400, 800, 1000, 1600, 3200
  int pulseWidth = 411; //Options: 69, 118, 215, 411
  int adcRange = 4096; //Options: 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384
  particleSensor.setup(ledBrightness, sampleAverage, ledMode, sampleRate, pulseWidth, adcRange); //Configure sensor with these settings
  startPulse();
  }
}

}
// Wait one touch
TSPoint waitOneTouch() { 
  TSPoint p;
  do {
    p= ts.getPoint(); 
    pinMode(XM, OUTPUT); //Pins configures again for TFT control
    pinMode(YP, OUTPUT);
  } while((p.z < MINPRESSURE )|| (p.z > MAXPRESSURE));
  return p;
}
void sensereset()
{
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  TSPoint p = ts.getPoint();     // Read touchscreen
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  pinMode(XM, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(YP, OUTPUT);
  if (p.x < 199 && p.y < 293 && !running)
    resetsensed = true;
  else
    resetsensed = false;
}
void startPedo()        //-------------------pedometer function--------------------------
{
  int acc = 0;
  float totvect[100] = {0};
  float totave[100] = {0};
  float xaccl[100] = {0};
  float yaccl[100] = {0};
  float zaccl[100] = {0};
  for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++)
  {
    xaccl[a] = float(analogRead(xpin) - 345);
    delay(1);
    yaccl[a] = float(analogRead(ypin) - 346);
    delay(1);
    zaccl[a] = float(analogRead(zpin) - 416);
    delay(1);
    totvect[a] = sqrt(((xaccl[a] - xavg) * (xaccl[a] - xavg)) + ((yaccl[a] - yavg) * (yaccl[a] - yavg)) + ((zval[a] - zavg) * (zval[a] - zavg)));
    totave[a] = (totvect[a] + totvect[a - 1]) / 2 ;
    Serial.println("totave[a]");
    Serial.println(totave[a]);
    delay(100);
    if (totave[a] > threshold && flag == 0)
    {
      steps = steps + 1;
      flag = 1;
    }
    else if (totave[a] > threshold && flag == 1)
    {
      // Don't Count
    }
    if (totave[a] < threshold   && flag == 1)
    {
      flag = 0;
    }
    if (steps < 0) {
      steps = 0;
    }
    Serial.println('\n');
    Serial.print("steps: ");
    Serial.println(steps);
    delay(1000);
  }
  delay(1000);
  //print results on lcd
  tft.setCursor(130, 145);
  tft.setTextSize(3);
  tft.setTextColor(TFT_WHITE);
  tft.print(steps);

  }
void calibrate()            //<----------------------calibrate funtion--------------------->
{
  float sum = 0;
  float sum1 = 0;
  float sum2 = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    xval[i] = float(analogRead(xpin) - 345);
    sum = xval[i] + sum;
  }
  delay(100);
  xavg = sum / 100.0;
  Serial.println(xavg);
  for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
  {
    yval[j] = float(analogRead(ypin) - 346);
    sum1 = yval[j] + sum1;
  }
  yavg = sum1 / 100.0;
  Serial.println(yavg);
  delay(100);
  for (int q = 0; q < 100; q++)
  {
    zval[q] = float(analogRead(zpin) - 416);
    sum2 = zval[q] + sum2;
  }
  zavg = sum2 / 100.0;
  delay(100);
  Serial.println(zavg);
}
void senseBack()
{
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  TSPoint p = ts.getPoint();     // Read touchscreen
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);

  pinMode(XM, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(YP, OUTPUT);
  if (p.y < 305 && p.x < 285 && p.x > 239 && !running)
  {
    backsensed = true;

  }
  else
    backsensed = false;
}
void startGlu()                 //-------------------------------startGlu-------------------------
{
  }
void startPulse()             //--------------------------------startpulse-----------------------
{
  bufferLength = 100; //buffer length of 100 stores 4 seconds of samples running at 25sps

  //read the first 100 samples, and determine the signal range
  for (byte i = 0 ; i < bufferLength ; i++)
  {
    while (particleSensor.available() == false) //do we have new data?
      particleSensor.check(); //Check the sensor for new data
    redBuffer[i] = particleSensor.getRed();
    irBuffer[i] = particleSensor.getIR();
    particleSensor.nextSample(); //We're finished with this sample so move to next sample
    Serial.print(F("red="));
    Serial.print(redBuffer[i], DEC);
    Serial.print(F(", ir="));
    Serial.println(irBuffer[i], DEC);
  }
  //calculate heart rate and SpO2 after first 100 samples (first 4 seconds of samples)
  maxim_heart_rate_and_oxygen_saturation(irBuffer, bufferLength, redBuffer, &spo2, &validSPO2, &heartRate, &validHeartRate);
  //Continuously taking samples from MAX30102.  Heart rate and SpO2 are calculated every 1 second
  while (1)
  {
    //dumping the first 25 sets of samples in the memory and shift the last 75 sets of samples to the top
    for (byte i = 25; i < 100; i++)
    {
      redBuffer[i - 25] = redBuffer[i];
      irBuffer[i - 25] = irBuffer[i];
    }
    //take 25 sets of samples before calculating the heart rate.
    for (byte i = 75; i < 100; i++)
    {
      while (particleSensor.available() == false) //do we have new data?
        particleSensor.check(); //Check the sensor for new data
      digitalWrite(readLED, !digitalRead(readLED)); //Blink onboard LED with every data read
      redBuffer[i] = particleSensor.getRed();
      irBuffer[i] = particleSensor.getIR();
      particleSensor.nextSample(); //We're finished with this sample so move to next sample
      //send samples and calculation result to terminal program through UART
      Serial.print(F("red="));
      Serial.print(redBuffer[i], DEC);
      Serial.print(F(", ir="));
      Serial.print(irBuffer[i], DEC);
      Serial.print(F(", HR="));
      Serial.print(heartRate, DEC);
      Serial.print(F(", HRvalid="));
      Serial.print(validHeartRate, DEC);
      Serial.print(F(", SPO2="));
      Serial.print(spo2, DEC);
      Serial.print(F(", SPO2Valid="));
      Serial.println(validSPO2, DEC);
    }

    //After gathering 25 new samples recalculate HR and SP02
    maxim_heart_rate_and_oxygen_saturation(irBuffer, bufferLength, redBuffer, &spo2, &validSPO2, &heartRate, &validHeartRate);
    //print results on lcd
    tft.setCursor(130,145);
  tft.setTextSize(3);
  tft.setTextColor(TFT_WHITE);
  tft.print(heartRate);

  }
    
}
```

Please see above code whether it works perfect as i want. I am getting error when i try to compile this code which is given below
[image]

My questions are:

1. whether this code is right, if not then point out my mistakes.
2. Solution of error shown in image.

Comment: please, no pictures of text .. not everyone is able to view images ... post the actual text

Comment: `code is right?` ... if it does what you expect, then `yes` .... otherwise `no`

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino Uno doesn't have enough SRAM, the current Rev3 has just 2 KB. You can circumvent that by using less variables, use `#define xpin` instead of `const int`, etc.
[Here](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/john-bradnam/reducing-your-memory-usage-26ca05) is an article about how to reduce memory usage, give it a try.
Another option is to use a different Microcontroller with more SRAM, with at least 3KB like a Arduino Mega, ESP32. But first try to optimize your program, if you don't have another unused board lying around anyway.

**EDIT:**
You might also take a look at the header files if you can optimize anything there.

Comment: Ok i am trying to make this code optimized.

Comment: @Nimra I think you have to find the right number of arrays being saved in memory and the right number of them saved in Flash, because you don't have that much space on the Flash left over either.

Answer (score 1):

Arduino Mega has **8192 bytes** of SRAM which will solve your problem.

Reduce the RAM usage ([ref](https://arduinojson.org/v6/how-to/reduce-memory-usage/))

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Look [at this post](https://www.fpaynter.com/2021/02/digital-clock-project/), where I have implement the clock using a tft touch-enabled screen, with touch-enabled choice boxes for setting the time.  I used a Teensy 3.2, which handles the memory requirements nicely.  From the compile report

```
Compiling 'Teensy_LCDClockV4' for 'Teensy 3.2 / 3.1'
Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\Frank\AppData\Local\Temp\VMBuilds\Teensy_LCDClockV4\teensy31\Release\pch\Arduino.h.gch
Program size: 117,320 bytes (used 45% of a 262,144 byte maximum) (4.14 secs)
Minimum Memory Usage: 5936 bytes (9% of a 65536 byte maximum)
```

So you might have some trouble fitting it into a typical Arduino board